# Naming collision in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having a peculiar problem with a django template I'm setting up: I have a `{{ name }}` variable that I'm passing to my template, and at the same time, I have a `notes` list coming from a client-side api that has both a `{{ name }}` and a `{{ body }}`.
Whenever I try to print out the name of the note, the other `{{ name }}` shows up. Which is odd. Here's my code for the notes:

```
<div class="notes">
   {% for note in notes %}
       <p><strong>{{ name }}</strong></p>
       <p>{{ body }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a context operator I can use or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake that is made when working with Handlebars alongside Django since Handlebars changes scope automatically for you. All you need to do is refer to the `note` variable you created with the for loop:

```
<div class="notes">
    {% for note in notes %}
        <p><strong>{{ note.name }}</strong></p>
        <p>{{ note.body }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-for

Comment: Ahhh what an astute observation! I'm totally using backbone.js with handlebars. Makes sense! Thanks for that, I'll try to keep them straight in the future.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="notes">
   {% for note in notes %}
       <p><strong>{{ note.name }}</strong></p>
       <p>{{ note.body }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```